# Move code from HTML to Directive in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have the following angular code to calculate a ratio and 'select' a level in a table row:

```
  <form>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="N" />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="D" />
    <p class="value" data-ng-show="!!(!!N && !!D && D != 0)">{{ N/D | number: 1 }}</p>
  </form>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td data-ng-class="{'active': N/D < 0.5}">Low</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-ng-class="{'active': N/D >= 0.5">High</td>
    </tr>
  <table>
```

In this example I am using N/D but in fact the calculation is a little bit longer then this ...

Can a directive be created to remove all the logic from the HTML?

I think a directive might be better then a controller for this case, no?

Comment: If this is a single-use-case, then a controller should be fine too. You can create as many controllers as you need and they can oversee as detailed a scope as you want

Comment: You can also move that condition into a function and call the function there `ng-show="shouldShow()"` if that helps.

Comment: I have something like 5 or 6 like this but each one varies a little bit on the number or variables and table rows ... So i was wondering if i should create a directive,  use 5 controllers or simple leve the code in the html since it is not to complex

Answer (score 0):

Sure, instead of an inline expression, you can use a function and write this function in your directive.

For instance the HTML could be:

```
data-ng-show="isShown()"
```

And in your directive:

```
// you can also use controller instead of link
link: function(scope) {
  scope.isShown = function() {
    var D = scope.D;
    var N = scope.N;
    return !!(!!N && !!D && D != 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can a single directive control the calculations in the form and the classification in the table?